# XMLHTTPREQUEST or AJAX Update panel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2008, xmlhttprequest

whenever I've used Ajax, I've used asp.net Ajax update panel and script manager provided in visual studio (and Ajax extensions if I needed them), but just recently I bought [this (Pro Ajax and .Net 2.0 Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596706) and in this book the whole focus of Ajax has been XMLHTTPREQUEST, and there is no discussion of script manager, update panel or what so ever.
So, I wanted to know, is there any difference between these two or is this visual studio's update manager is just a wrapper around XMLHTTPREQUEST? Also, which one is better performance wise, or are they just the same? And finally, which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Script Manager`, `Update Panel` are Microsoft implementation of the AJAX framework. Internally it use `XmlHttpRequest` to make out-of-bound request.

Check out the below list of AJAX framework from wiki.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ajax_frameworks

Microsoft AJAX implementation is type of full framework which provide rich programming model including server side controls, services and client side scripts. Eg. Update Panel server control lets you execute server-side code and return updated markup to the client browser with out-of-bound request.

But as for performance wise, it would be slower than service base/ajax because although out-of-bound request, UpdatePanel is really a post back to the server which will go through the full page life cycle.